# NSURLSession completion block not called

Tags: macos, ios8, nsurlsession

```
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, 
                            completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, 
                                                 response: NSURLResponse!,                       
                                                 error: NSError!) in
                                                      println(data)
                                                      println(response)
                                                      println(error)
                                               })
```

So I am making this request, and the completion block is never called.

What's wrong?

Also I tried a `synchronous and asynchronous form` of the same request with `NSURLConnection` and it worked perfectly.

EDIT:

I tried assigning a `dataTask` variable to the `session.dataTaskWithRequest` and displayed it right after. It says this `<__NSCFLocalDataTask: 0xb41bda0> { suspended }` Suspended? Why?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

So I tried calling it like this

```
session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, 
                        completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, 
                                             response: NSURLResponse!,                       
                                             error: NSError!) in
                                                  print(data)
                                                  print(response)
                                                  print(error)
                                           }).resume()
```

And it worked.

Seems like I have to call `resume()` on a default suspended session task.

Comment: Yes. This is the same in Swift or Objective C; all NSURLSession tasks start in a suspended state and must be "resumed" to kick them off. It's Objective C-based, but [this NSURLSession tutorial from raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial) is the best non-Apple example of NSURLSession code I've come across, so having a look through that might help you work out how best to use it.

Comment: didn't help me at all :(

Comment: @SergeVelikanov what did you try?

Comment: @BlackFlam3, nevermind, I'm using AFNetworking now and it works like a charm

Answer (score 7):

Are you using playgrounds??

If you are, you should be careful to include:

```
 XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(continueIndefinitely: true)
```

In order to make the playground wait for the callback

Comment: You'll need to `import XCPlayground` too.

Answer (score 5):

I face the same problem and I solved it by

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error) {

    if (!error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Data is %@",data);
        NSLog(@"Response is %@",response);
        NSLog(@"Error is %@",error);
    }
 }];

[dataTask resume];
```

And check that you are added the `App Transport Security Settings` in your `info.plist`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use it simply by :-

```
let url = "api url"

let nsURL = NSURL

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL) {
(data, response, error) in
   // your condition on success and failure
}

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly unique case, but if you're using a URLSession inside a unit test, you'll need to setup the expectations.  Otherwise, your test case will end and it will *appear* that your request is never returning.  Swift 3.0.1.

```
    let expect = expectation(description: "dataTaskWithRequest - completes")

    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/") {

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { ( data, response, error) in

            print(data.debugDescription)
            print(response.debugDescription)
            print(error.debugDescription)

            expect.fulfill()

        }.resume()

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll be something like this in Swift 2.x

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(theRequest) { (data, response , error) in
    print(response)
}.resume()
```